# Up to date, but says I need an update?

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 13.04. There's a yellow update icon in my panel and when I click it, there is an unclickable grayed out options that says "There is 1 update available". When I click on the option to show updates, it says my computer is up to date.

I've tried sudo apt-get update, but it does not remove the message. What can I do to get this updated or at least remove it? I do not know what the update is because there is nothing telling me what it wants to update.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. That should show you what is being updated and any errors related to that package.

Comment: Okay, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the GUI methods of upgrading your packages don't always work. When they don't work, you can use `apt-get` on the command line to upgrade your system's packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```